# Javascript indexOf() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexof

I am working on a service that randomly generates a URL and then uploads some pasted HTML code to the URL with PHP `fwrite().` As a precation, I added a system to check if the URL has already been taken:

```
var URL = "thehtmlworkshop.com/test4.html";
$('#existingurls').load('existingurls.txt');
var existing = $('#existingurls').html();
var isunique = existing.indexOf( URL );
if (isunique == -1) {
alert('Form submit');
} else {
alert('Whoops! Looks like the randomly generated URL was already taken. Please try again (this will be automatic in future).');
}
```

`existingurls.txt` contains all the created URLs. When I first tried it, to test what would happen when the URL was a duplicate of a current URL, instead of using the random 7 letter string generator I just put one of the URLs already in the `txt` file.

This is the contents of `existingurls.txt`:

```
thehtmlworkshop.com/test1.html
thehtmlworkshop.com/test2.html
thehtmlworkshop.com/test3.html
thehtmlworkshop.com/test4.html
thehtmlworkshop.com/test5.html
```

Anyway, what should happen is that `indexOf` searches for all occurances of 'thehtmlworkshop.com/test4.html' and return it's position as 91 or whatever its position is and it would then tell the user that the randomly generated URL was taken. However, it seems to return `-1` each time because it always goes to the submit form dialog.

NOTE: Yes, I am using jQuery.

Comment: All together now: **A** jax is **Asynchronous**...

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var URL = "thehtmlworkshop.com/test4.html";
$('#existingurls').load('existingurls.txt', function () {
    var existing = $('#existingurls').html();
    var isunique = existing.indexOf(URL);
    if (isunique == -1) {
        alert('Form submit');
    } else {
        alert('Whoops! Looks like the randomly generated URL was already taken. Please try again (this will be automatic in future).');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the list on the Success call of the ajax function to make sure it's loaded.

```
var URL = "thehtmlworkshop.com/test4.html";
$('#existingurls').load('existingurls.txt', function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  } else {
    var isunique = existing.indexOf(URL);
    if (isunique == -1) {
      alert('Form submit');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ahhh, the answer is already up there. Sorry, I added the code 1minute after.